# Does this query get the past 7 days?

Tags: mysql, database

I want to ensure this  query is correct. I've read the documentation and I believe it is, but I'm looking for the help of some MySql veterans to confirm.

When this query runs, it should return the list of Users created between yesterday and a  week before yesterday.

```
SELECT *
FROM User WHERE DateCreated BETWEEN 
    ((NOW() -INTERVAL 1 DAY) - INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND
    (NOW() -INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `(NOW() -INTERVAL 1 DAY) - INTERVAL 7 DAY` is the same as `Now() - INTERVAL 8 DAY` which would be August 30th (Thursday of last week). So it would include new users that were created on that day. If that's what you want AND `DateCreated` is a Date type and not a DateTime type, then it looks ok to me.

Comment: `((NOW() -INTERVAL 1 DAY) - INTERVAL 7 DAY)` is basically -8 days so if you run it today (2018-09-07) you get the range `2018-09-30 - 2018-09-06`... Also a hint when you are in doubt about calculations in SQL of any kind which you use in the `ON (when joining)/WHERE/HAVING` clauses you can simply check it running a `SELECT ((NOW() -INTERVAL 1 DAY) - INTERVAL 7 DAY)` and `SELECT (NOW() -INTERVAL 1 DAY)` to verify the calculations

Comment: Couldn't you create some sample data and check that really quick?

Comment: I also agree with @NicoHaase on this one. I wouldn't trust strangers on the internet more than my own eyes. Do the `DateCreated` values returned from that query match your expectations?

Comment: Yeah the results seem okay. This was mostly a sanity check since I have no one else to confer with. Thanks everyone.

Comment: .Actually, you want to subtract 7 days instead of 8.

Comment: "Actually, you want to subtract 7 days instead of 8" "When this query runs, it should return the list of Users created **between yesterday and a week before yesterday**. " @SalmanA thats -8

Comment: Just to settle any confusion, I basically need Thursday of last week to Thursday (yesterday) included in the query.

Comment: OK so confusion eliminted but then Thursday to Thursday is 8 days (assuming both are inclusive) .

Comment: Did you also read mine comment about testing SQL calculations yourself in the future so you don't get a confusion which you can in the WHERE clause? @FNTNBWIH ...

Comment: @RaymondNijland Yes I did. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @SalmanA That "8 days" always drives me nuts with people asking for this in their data. "I want the last 7 days of data" and they won't specify anything more than that. If today is Friday, do they want Friday to Thursday? Thursday to Thursday? Friday to Current Time? One of the strange discrepancies between spoken language and code.

Comment: @JNevill exactly. The question looks straight forward but it is not. Depends on (i) is `DateCreated` a date or datetime (ii) if it is Fri 12:00PM what happens to users created on/after Thu 12:00PM (iii) 7 days from Thu is Fri...Thu, not Thu...Thu (assuming we're counting both).